# Cost of Google Cloud PubSub when there are no messages

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I was taking a look Pub/Sub pricing and I couldn't get what would be the price if the subscriber hit the endpoint but doesn't get any message. Because my idea is run a worker 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

With the pricing model as of today, if your subscriber sends a [Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Pull) or [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.StreamingPull) request (either directly or through the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries)), it will not incur a cost if no messages are returned. Billing for subscribers is based on the number of bytes in the messages sent to the subscribers per month.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Cloud Pub/Sub pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing), the pricing is based on the amount of data used in a calendar month. Data volume is computed from message and attribute data for pull, push, and publish operations. 
So even if there are no messages available in your subscription, you still perform a pull call and that call has a certain size with a certain price.

Note that the minimum billable volume of data per request (not per message in a request) is 1 KB of data. So even if the pull action is smaller than 1 kB, you are charged for 1 kB. When in one calendar month 50 pull action are executed, each with a size of 500 bytes, the cost for those pull actions is 1 KB * 50 requests * price/GiB in that data volume tier.

How much you are charged for a certain amount of monthly data volume is described in the pricing table in the documentation link above. Notice that there is a certain first amount of data volume for free. The next data volume tiers are not for free.

UPDATE:

I am not able to comment on [Kamal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111173/4819605) here. But taking into account he works on Pub/Sub at Google, I expect his answer to be correct and not mine.

In that case I find the documentation unclear since it emphasizes "per request (not message)".

> The minimum billable volume of data per request (not message) is 1 KB of data.

The documentation does not explicitly say you are not billed if there are no messages returned. But according to Kamal, that seems to be the case.